# access an array stored inside another array excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create an array inside a function (arrayA), Function (store). I would like the function store to return array A, and I would store the functions return value in a larger array ArrayB. After which I would like to print out each of arrayA's elements by stored in arrayB element (1).

Please help, many thanks, my code is below.

```
dim arrA() as variant
dim arrB() as variant

redim arrB(1)

arrb(1) = store(arrA)

for i = 1 to ubound(arrB(1)
debug.print arrB(1)(i)
next i

function store(A() as variant)

redim a(1 to 3, 1 to 3)

a(1,3) = "1"
a(1,2)="2"

store = A

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the contents of `arrA` you'll have to iterate through it like this:

```
For i = 1 to UBound(arrB(1))
   For j = LBound(arrB(1), 2) To UBound(arrB(1), 2)
      Debug.Print arrB(1)(i, j)
   Next
Next
```

The 2nd argument of the `LBound`/`UBound` functions is used to choose the dimension that we want; in this case, we want the 2nd one because the outer `For` is already going through the 1st.

Comment: I want to print the elements in arrayA but Debug.Print arrB(1)(i, 2) does not work.

Comment: And for the record I said I wanted to return a small array (ArrayA) as the result of a function,store the smaller array in a larger array (ArrayB) and I wanted to loop through the elements of arrayA stored at position ArrayB(1).

But your saying array B and array A have to be the same size and number of dimensions?

Comment: Totally misunderstood in the 1st read. I'm sorry. I've edited my answer; I hope it's now what you asked for.